# java how to check version being used by 'jar launcher.app' on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, jar, executable-jar

I have several .jar files that run successfully when opened with Mac's built in 'Jar Launcher' (Version 15.0.1) but when ran from terminal they error out.

Looking online the error messages might be down to the incorrect version of Java being linked to the terminal version, so I'd like to check if the options set for 'Jar Launcher' and the Java used within terminal are the same.

Does there exist any way to do this?

Comment: Any news on that one?

Answer (score 4):

This question is two years old, but as there is no answer to it, I thought I'd put my two cents here since I've had issues myself, and have made some observations.

It seems that the Jar Launcher doesn't necessarily use the same JVM version as the one shown by the command `/usr/libexec/java_home`: If there is a JRE `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`, then the Jar Launcher will use it and ignore anything in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`.

I've solve my problem of version mismatch between the Jar Launcher and the terminal by removing the JRE:

1. Go to /Library/Internet Plug-Ins.
2. Remove the JavaAppletPlugin.plugin directory by executing the rm command as a root user or by using the sudo tool.
3. Go to /Library/PreferencePanes.
4. Remove JavaControlPanel.prefpane by executing the rm command as a root user or by using the sudo tool.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-macos.htm